# Git log decorated graph with appended information

Tags: git

Well the git log command,

```
git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

[image]

shows me really niced graph. 
Note that the above git command applies automatic beautiful colours to "(refs/heads/, refs/tags/ and refs/remotes/)" part.

I wish I could append along with the existing format:

```
*<abbrevated commit> (refs/heads/, refs/tags/ and refs/remotes/) <commit message>
```

appending to the end

```
<relative date> <Vorname nachname>
```

finally looks like

```
*<abbrevated commit> (refs/heads/, refs/tags/ and refs/remotes/)* <commit message> <relative date> <Vorname nachname>
```

I tried the command:

```
git log --graph\n--pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'\n--abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

[image]
which gives me the same content but the the automatice colours now its is not applied on the %d parameter. Now if I wont force with yellow then, the "reset" colour is applied.

In Simple I want as below **(edited image to show the Demo)**
[image]
Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

Wrap `%d` like this:

```
%C(auto)%d%Creset
```

to get the automatic decoration coloring.

The auto coloring depends on git version >= 1.8.3: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt#n72

Comment: it doesn't work, says:

fatal: bad color value 'auto' for variable '--pretty format'

Comment: Ok Found that, auto is only possibly from the git Version: git 1.8.3

Comment: oh interesting! do you have a reference for that?

Comment: please refer the below link is page,5th point in the "
UI, Workflows & Features" section

https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt